# Why does nothing showing up on my plot even with defined variables

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So i made this code to create a plot that should look like this[This image was done in Mathematica] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82xp1.png) but for some reason nothing shows up on the plot [plot i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcQ3N.png).does it have to something with the gam(x_2) or gam itself because i tried defining that as a range but still nothing. please teach me. From the plot made in matematica it seems like he set both the x and y ranges all the way up to 10,000.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pylab

%matplotlib inline


gam0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15
def gam(x_2):
return gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log10(1+628.14*55.556*x_2)

x = range(0, 10000)
x_2= x



plt.plot('gam(x_2), x_2')

plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
```

Comment: Try to use `plt.show()` at the end of your script.

Comment: I tried that nothing showed up

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes needed; defining your function, there's an indent missing, also multiplying the whole array with ' * ' isn't working, so you can save up the values in a separate array through a for loop:

EDIT: Oh, and also while plotting, you don't put the variable names as strings, you just call them as they are.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pylab

%matplotlib inline


gam0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15

x = range(0, 10000)
x_2= x

def gam(x_2):
    returns = []
    for x_i in x_2:
        returns.append(gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log10(1+628.14*55.556*x_i))
    return returns

plt.plot(gam(x_2), x_2)

plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely a step in the right direction. I just need to figure out how to match the scales and plot in the mathematica version

Answer (score 0):

Indent your function

```
def gam(x_2):
    return gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log10(1+628.14*55.556*x_2)
```

Find `gam(x_2)` for each item(`x_2`) in list `x`

```
gam_x = [gam(x_2) for x_2 in x]
```

Finally, plot and show.

```
plt.plot(gam_x, x)

plt.xlabel('Log_10x_2')
plt.ylabel('gamma (erg cm^2)')
plt.show()
```